# How do local party-government leaders get promoted in China?

Tags: china

How do local party-government leaders get promoted in China? I've heard that the system is merit-based and I've also heard the opposite and heard that it's extremely corrupt, so I would like to understand how the process of getting promoted from local party-government leaders in China looks like and how the decision gets made.

Comment: It is likely both. Merit based in the fact that is how promotions are judged but corrupt based on how the decision makers actually pick people. To me it sounds like a system is put in place but it gets corrupted once people get involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult one, and even residents here like me only understand figuratively outside the system.

The merit-based aspect is that there is always tasks for each time period that you need to achieve. For example how many under your governance to get out of poverty, what GDP figure you need to achieve (due to the historical reasons, these figures are calculated carefully to avoid tasks that cannot be completed).

When you do these tasks well, you are then considered capable by your superiors and maybe even the center and may be moved to another position, often higher up. Else you will likely considered incompetent and be replaced. If there is something you made a mess, you will be punished severely (all the way to jail).

That's the idea of the system in how it's supposed to work. Like it's said, there's always possibility of corruption, especially down all the way to the village, community level. That's where the extension of jurisdiction come into place, where central-assigned officials with no local connections are sent to inspect the actual conditions. Of course, these can also be corrupted, but are much more manageable and in much smaller numbers.

Similar to the idea of choosing these inspecting officials, the provincial level governors are often from other locations with no local connections nowadays. This also contributes to reducing the 'behind the scene' work.

In essence, China is a large country, and large countries need to have a strong central government to be effective, as opposed to small country with little population where as 老子 (What's the translation again?) says "无为而治" (To govern without governing).

The problem of a large country is not a wayward central, but the unruly small officials that have power similar to kings within a village or community. The central is always kept in check by the numerous people and factions that they need to strike a balance. And as in Chinese history, the stronger the central, the more prosperous the whole country.

Of course there's also the education campaigns promoting communist ideals and aligning goals within the party, but I don't think people from other culture can really grasp the essence. Those are metaphysical when compared to the forms.

Comment: Also, note that China's political structure is not the same as western ones. National People's Congress is structurally the highest power in China, is the legislation facility, and all power comes from there. The government and jurisdiction are put into power by law. In China, NPC represents the will of the people, and the CCP is historically and currently chosen by the people to lead, and represents the ones more willing to take the effort of betterment of the state. Thus, CCP is really not part of the government, but a collection of people, not just a party in politics in western sense.

Comment: Of course, the latter part of the comment is from textbooks and classes, but I find that quite justified by the things being done.